# What does Array.remove = function() {...} mean?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I came across this piece of code that I am not able to understand -:

```
Array.remove = function(array, from, to) {
    var rest = array.slice((to || from) + 1 || array.length);
    array.length = from < 0 ? array.length + from : from;
    return array.push.apply(array, rest);
};
```

What does it mean ? Does mean I am over riding the default `remove()` function of my web browser ? Is this even compatible in older browsers ?

Also more confusing is how the function is called-:

```
Array.remove(foo, bar);
```

As can see there are two actual parameters while the function lists three formal parameters. How does the function know which one to use ?

Comment: thats just a "static" function.

Comment: My browser does not have any native `Array.remove` method.

Comment: Read this http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-array-remove/ and `Array.remove(foo, bar)` is used when you extend Array prototype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does it mean ? Does mean I am over riding the default remove() function of my web browser ?

It means that you are adding a method called "remove" to the global `Array` object. If it already had a method by that name, you would be overriding it.

> Is this even compatible in older browsers ?

Yes, pretty much any browser will allow you to do this.

> As can see there are two actual parameters while the function lists three formal parameters. How does the function know which one to use ?

Javascript doesn't care how many arguments you pass to a function. It will match up the provided arguments in place order, and assign `undefined` to any that don't have values provided.

Answer (score 0):

You don't override array.remove. Its a static methode that: 'allows you to simply remove an item – or a group of items – from an array'

source: http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-array-remove/